# python pandas - selecting part of DataFrame by two axes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Let's say I have this DataFrame (df):

```
            A           B           C            D
2013-01-05  0.785969    1.381685    -0.547796   -1.155653
2013-01-03  1.322663    0.343046    0.634790    -1.037137
2013-01-02  -0.132650   -0.030817   0.613637    -1.088943
2013-01-01  1.261990    -0.078801   0.425255    0.105730
2013-01-06  0.012660    -0.259059   -0.729147   0.122075
2013-01-04  -0.638154   -0.952552   0.895817    -0.749750
```

I know how to get a cross section of columns A and B and all rows:

```
df.loc[:,["A", "B"]]
```

But how do I get a cross section of some columns **and some rows**?

I tried stuff like

```
df.loc[[2:], ["A", "B"]]
```

but that just returns an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `iloc`:

```
df.iloc[2:, [0, 1]]
```

You can find the documentation [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html).

Answer (score 2):

Because [ix is deprecated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#ix-indexer-is-deprecated), you have 2 possible solutions if need select by positions (.iloc) with select by labels (.loc):

**1.**

Convert positions to index name by seelcting index `[]` - so select index and values by labels and then use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
print (df.index[2])
2013-01-02 00:00:00

df = df.loc[df.index[2]:, ["A", "B"]]
print (df)
                   A         B
2013-01-02 -0.132650 -0.030817
2013-01-01  1.261990 -0.078801
2013-01-06  0.012660 -0.259059
2013-01-04 -0.638154 -0.952552
```

**2.**

Conver columns names to positions by [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) by [`get_indexer`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_indexer.html) and then seelct by [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
print (df.columns.get_indexer(["A", "B"]))
[0 1]

df = df.iloc[2:, df.columns.get_indexer(["A", "B"])]
print (df)
                   A         B
2013-01-02 -0.132650 -0.030817
2013-01-01  1.261990 -0.078801
2013-01-06  0.012660 -0.259059
2013-01-04 -0.638154 -0.952552
```

Comment: Sorry for the previous comment, my bad. It's working perfectly, thank you!

Comment: Supeer, glad can help!

Answer (score 1):

**You could try to use iloc() method**

Multiple columns and rows can be selected together using the .iloc indexer.

## Multiple row and column selections using iloc and DataFrame

```
data.iloc[0:5] # first five rows of dataframe
data.iloc[:, 0:2] # first two columns of data frame with all rows
data.iloc[[2:], ["A","B"]] # 1st, 4th, 7th, 25th row + 1st 6th 7th columns.
data.iloc[0:5, 5:8] # first 5 rows and 5th, 6th, 7th columns of data frame (county -> phone1).
```